# In the Depths of the Mediterranean

Tags: climate, water

The average depth of the Mediterranean Sea is 1500 meters.

If that average depth increases to 3767 meters, how greatly will it affect the entire region?

Comment: Should answers include the sudden appearance of a new undersea crevice, or do we assume the Earth formed that way?

Comment: Always the latter.

Comment: Can you narrow this question?  Are we talking politics, agriculture, technological development, or something else?

Comment: Geography, climatology, ecology.

Comment: Even with this edit, this is incredibly broad.  Answering how an entire ecosystem will change based on an increase in depth is just too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Given that in this world the Mediterranean sea is deeper, mountain ranges around the Mediterranean like the Alps and the Apennines will be higher than in our world due to Tectonic activity.  A deeper Mediterranean sea would also mean that the life that comes to inhabit the Mediterranean will be different as by having a deeper sea you open up aquatic zones that may be inhabited by sea animals that are accustomed to living in seas 3000-4000+ meters in depth (since you said average depth, this means the Mediterranean now has regions over 5 kilos deep).

Deep sea creatures in the Mediterranean may actually get more biodiversity than that seen in the oceans because of the multiple basins the Mediterranean sea has for the similar reasons areas with multiple different trenches can be bio-diverse.

If civilizations like the roman empire or greeks still arise, they'd have to deal with even more intense storms than what they dealt with in the Mediterranean of our world.

Comment: How much more intense?

Comment: Teutonic activity? Are you sure that's what you mean...and 3000km deep?